# Post notification redirect user to post id

Tags: laravel, notifications, http-redirect

i have database notification, and i was trying to redirect the user whenever they click one of the notification link it will go to the exact POST id,then mark as read that particular notification being selected. but i couldn't make it work

**Here is my controller**

```
 public function readbyid($id){

    if(isset($notification->data['id'])){
        return redirect()->action(
            'PostController@show', ['id' => $notification->data['id']]
        );
    }else{
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**Notification Model**

```
 public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->post->id,
    ];
}
```

**Blade View:**

```
  <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a id="messages" rel="nofollow" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i>@if (auth()->user()->unreadnotifications->count())<span class="badge badge-warning">{{auth()->user()->unreadnotifications->count()}}</span>@endif</a>
              <ul aria-labelledby="notifications" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a rel="nofollow" href="{{Url('markread')}}" class="dropdown-item all-notifications text-center"> <strong> <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>Mark all as Read</strong></a></li>
              @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadnotifications as $notify)
                <li><a rel="nofollow" href="{{Url('markread/{id}')}}" class="dropdown-item d-flex"> 

                    <div class="msg-body">
                    <h3 class="h5">{{$notify->data['title']}}</h3>
                    </div> </a></li>@endforeach
              </ul>
            </li>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('markread/{id}', 'NotifyController@readbyid' );
```

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: i want to redirect the user to the post everytime they click one of the notification

Comment: is it possible? without using vue.js

Comment: just add your post link

Comment: how to add the post link?